# Replace part of string with span

Tags: javascript

I have this following value : `First&nbsp;Second`
I want to replace it and have the following instead : `<div style="display:hidden;">First</div>&nbsp;Second`

Knowing that `First` are random words, they're not to be trusted. What is to be trusted that everything before `&` needs to be replaced.

I tried this but it doesn't work, any idea why?

```
var string = state.text.substr(0, state.text.indexOf('&')); 
state.text.replace(string, '<span style="display:hidden;">' + string + '</span>')
```

Any hints would be appreciated :)

Comment: What exactly does not work? Seems fine. But `replace` returns a *new* string, you have to assign it to something, e.g.: `state.text = state.text.replace(...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine except for one thing, `replace`(as you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)) returns a new `String`, it doesn't modify the original one, so you would've to do:

```
state.text = state.text.replace(string, '<span style="display:hidden;">' + string + '</span>')
```

So that your change modifies `state.text`.